# Word for something added that does not improve functionality or performance

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Imagine this situation: I am working on a university programming project with another classmate. We agree that I do section A, and he does section B. I finish section A early and decide to also do section B for fun. I finish section B. In the meeting with my group mate we realise my section B is much better than his. So we use my section A and my section B for the final project. We decide to also include his section B in the final code to show that he did his part, though his section B is unused by any of the program built from the combined code. What word can I use to refer to his code. There is a word, similar to garbage, that I can't seem to remember.

Comment: Code that cannot execute but exists in the code base is refereed to as ***dead code***

Comment: @Jim I am aware of that one, but I am looking for a general word, something not specific to programming. For example a non functional second exhaust tip on a car.

Comment: Decorative, a facade, non-functional, just for show, extraneous...

Comment: @Jim I googled 'facade' and came across 'fake' which then led me to the word I was looking for: 'bogus'. It seems 'bogus' does not directly apply to the scenario I described, though it was the word I was looking for. Your answer did help me find it, so if you post one of those words as an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: **Dead Weight** if you don't want to be code specific.

Comment: pnizzle, post what you have found as an answer to your OP and then officially select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [**ornamental**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=ornamental+meaning&gws_rd=ssl) *adjective*: 1. serving or intended as an ornament; decorative.
>   "an *ornamental* fountain"; *synonyms*: decorative, fancy, ornate, ornamented; see, Google

Comment: the word I was looking for was bogus. Your suggestions are useful too.