# A word which means something that is now only for looks

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for a design element which used to have utility but now is used only for aesthetics? Ex: plastic "shutters" around some house windows, rivets on jeans, bead board.

Comment: Are you looking for something more than *decorative*?

Comment: Jim, yes. I heard a specific word for this type of thing on a radio program (possibly but not certainly Science Friday) some time ago. I don't remember when, so I can't find the program again.

Comment: Do any of these answer your question? https://english.stackexchange.com/q/251280/191178, https://english.stackexchange.com/q/173317/191178, https://english.stackexchange.com/q/360259/191178

Comment: Thanks Laurel, but no. However, the answer I'm looking for is included in this question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/417763/word-for-retaining-irrelevant-parts-of-old-design (skeuomorph)

Answer (score 1):

The word I was looking for is "skeuomorph".

Comment: I'll note that [Potemkin village](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potemkin_village) is another common term for this, though with a somewhat prejudicial tone.  And then there's [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A7ade).

Comment: Please add a linked and attributed supporting reference. How idiomatic is this term?